# How is energy conserved in interference of light waves?

Tags: optics, waves, energy-conservation, interference

How is energy conserved during interference of light waves? I already know a textbook explanation that in constructive interference the resulting intensity is four times the initial intensity and for destructive interference it is zero,so the net energy in youngs
double split experiment remain constant.But shouldn't energy be conserved in any closed system we consider? We can consider two rays that interfere constructively alone as a system.Also existence of bright fringes does not imply existence of dark fringes, I could add glass pieces over the region of board where destructive interference was supposed to be and prevent destructive interference to an extent and vice versa.Will energy be conserved in such a system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Energy conservation and interference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7707/)

Comment: Also [What happens to the energy when waves perfectly cancel each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23930/)

Comment: Energy is passed to the magnetic field

Comment: [What is the clear difference between interference and diffraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/709948/46708)